# How do I setup ssh so I can ssh back into my local machine

Tags: ssh

I need to be able to ssh back to my localhost, samwise.local in my case, but ssh on Mojave will only let me do this if I authorise by password and I need passwordless login. I've set ssh keys via ssh-keygen, then copied them using ssh-copy-id flink@samwise.local but to no effect, ssh keeps on demanding my login password.

The terminal session is below, including ssh -v output at the end

```
Last login: Fri Jan 25 11:17:19 from 192.168.1.28 
samwise:~ flink$ rm -rf .ssh 
samwise:~ flink$ ssh-keygen  
Generating public/private rsa key pair. 
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa):  
Created directory '/Users/flink/.ssh'. 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):  
Enter same passphrase again:  
Your identification has been saved in /Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa. 
Your public key has been saved in /Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. 
The key fingerprint is: 
SHA256:zyyv6N+5GKoTwCcWuVxr31XDye5QMcSgMr0Yt7TbnS8 flink@samwise.local 
The key's randomart image is: 
+---[RSA 2048]----+ 
|   .      .*+o   | 
|  o .  . .  O.   | 
| o + .+ =  + .   | 
|  B +  B +o .    | 
| . = ...S. o     | 
|    . . .* ...   |
|     .  + = o    | 
|    .  o * .E.   | 
|    .++.+.=. ..  | 
+----[SHA256]-----+ 
samwise:~ flink$ ls -la .ssh/ 
total 16 
drwx------   4 flink  staff   128 25 Jan 11:18 . 
drwxrwxrwx+ 30 flink  staff   960 25 Jan 11:18 .. 
-rw-------   1 flink  staff  1831 25 Jan 11:18 id_rsa 
-rw-r--r--   1 flink  staff   401 25 Jan 11:18 id_rsa.pub 
samwise:~ flink$ ssh flink@samwise.local 
The authenticity of host 'samwise.local (192.168.1.28)' can't be established. 
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:gHEngv0Vn4P/2DjF3soDQRltzuFhgsHCvY8s9UOszYc. 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
Warning: Permanently added 'samwise.local,192.168.1.28' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. 
Password: 
Last login: Fri Jan 25 11:18:09 2019 
samwise:~ flink$ exit 
logout 
Connection to samwise.local closed. 
samwise:~ flink$ ssh-copy-id flink@samwise.local 
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" 
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed 
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys 
Password: 

Number of key(s) added:        1 

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'flink@samwise.local'" 
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added. 

samwise:~ flink$ ls -la .ssh/ 
total 32 <br>
drwx------   6 flink  staff   192 25 Jan 11:19 . 
drwxrwxrwx+ 30 flink  staff   960 25 Jan 11:18 .. 
-rw-------   1 flink  staff   401 25 Jan 11:19 authorized_keys 
-rw-------   1 flink  staff  1831 25 Jan 11:18 id_rsa 
-rw-r--r--   1 flink  staff   401 25 Jan 11:18 id_rsa.pub 
-rw-r--r--   1 flink  staff   188 25 Jan 11:19 known_hosts 
samwise:~ flink$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys  
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDN07+JChrArXS2AjC547sG9sWw6vb1C3P7tXICzpZ96iJT4xyfe8bovUOHw5G9FHJ8gte2JrXQcQSUu9RCaoLTQLvRckI21l7JH7zCL28g+3Tp3V+5F9LFME5lCYnLoTmTW8pHZHtMh9BtbK/YWlwS3gAq39w1LfPr8rNJCEkmysL40DFvn7qFEQT+M/IXSgQn7ceeAl6zHe5ngGdJHiwHap6Y7qcxdwJXK9fcuYZ2GgzAKxetEIyYlrCU7TLdmkLSmEkSlLgVjRq60bFynimmRQfFeKgzgGUXQBZSzjxWl5V4Qu6GY3PkZvmMbekB0KJN6qftrhNd6G7s7Q5b2mWt flink@samwise.local 
samwise:~ flink$ cat .ssh/known_hosts  
samwise.local,192.168.1.28 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBDhhA65O8M2Z7h9f+7vrkUN8FRUn1vYanj/QLJIAYbQ+2cWICitc6KAyQ+/mZgHmoD2GpqAXK/ID/pRM4w6zdzc= 
samwise:~ flink$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub  
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDN07+JChrArXS2AjC547sG9sWw6vb1C3P7tXICzpZ96iJT4xyfe8bovUOHw5G9FHJ8gte2JrXQcQSUu9RCaoLTQLvRckI21l7JH7zCL28g+3Tp3V+5F9LFME5lCYnLoTmTW8pHZHtMh9BtbK/YWlwS3gAq39w1LfPr8rNJCEkmysL40DFvn7qFEQT+M/IXSgQn7ceeAl6zHe5ngGdJHiwHap6Y7qcxdwJXK9fcuYZ2GgzAKxetEIyYlrCU7TLdmkLSmEkSlLgVjRq60bFynimmRQfFeKgzgGUXQBZSzjxWl5V4Qu6GY3PkZvmMbekB0KJN6qftrhNd6G7s7Q5b2mWt flink@samwise.local 
samwise:~ flink$ ssh flink@samwise.local 
Password: 
Last login: Fri Jan 25 11:19:04 2019 from 192.168.1.28 
samwise:~ flink$ exit 
logout
Connection to samwise.local closed. 
samwise:~ flink$ ssh -v flink@samwise.local 
OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018 
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: Connecting to samwise.local [192.168.1.28] port 22. 
debug1: Connection established. 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa type 0 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_xmss type -1 
debug1: identity file /Users/flink/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1 
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9 
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9 
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000 
debug1: Authenticating to samwise.local:22 as 'flink' 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none 
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY 
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:gHEngv0Vn4P/2DjF3soDQRltzuFhgsHCvY8s9UOszYc 
debug1: Host 'samwise.local' is known and matches the ECDSA host key. 
debug1: Found key in /Users/flink/.ssh/known_hosts:1 
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent 
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received 
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zyyv6N+5GKoTwCcWuVxr31XDye5QMcSgMr0Yt7TbnS8 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_dsa  
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ecdsa  
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ed25519  
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_xmss  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received 
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521> 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive 
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:zyyv6N+5GKoTwCcWuVxr31XDye5QMcSgMr0Yt7TbnS8 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/flink/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive 
Password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive). 
Authenticated to samwise.local ([192.168.1.28]:22). 
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] 
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com 
debug1: Entering interactive session. 
debug1: pledge: network 
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0 
debug1: Remote: Ignored authorized keys: bad ownership or modes for directory /Users/flink 
Last login: Fri Jan 25 11:20:57 2019 from 192.168.1.28 
samwise:~ flink$ exit 
logout 
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0 
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1 
Connection to samwise.local closed. 
Transferred: sent 2700, received 2800 bytes, in 3.0 seconds 
Bytes per second: sent 902.8, received 936.2 
debug1: Exit status 1 
samwise:~ flink$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it might be your problem:

```
debug1: Remote: Ignored authorized keys: bad ownership or modes for directory /Users/flink
```

Your home directory seems to be world writeable (and the `..` line from your `ls -l .ssh` command supports this). That's no good, because it means any user on the computer can replace your .ssh directory, and thus your authorized_keys file.